# Centripetal force on a charged particle in a uniform electric field?

Tags: electric-fields

My teacher was showing us the factors that affect the motion of a charged particle in a uniform electric field. He derived an equation by equating force due to electric field and centripetal force

$$F_e = F_c$$
$$Eq = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$
$$r = \frac{mv^2}{Eq}$$

However, my question is that, is it possible to use the centripetal force in this case? I doubt it because the force will not always be perpendicular to the motion.

Comment: Maybe he meant the field generated by another (stationary) charge?

Comment: @andynitrox No he drew a stationary electric field with parallel plates

Comment: Hmm, I can't really make sense of this. Is it possible he was talking about a static magnetic field?

Comment: @andynitrox No, it was an electric field due to 2 parallel plates with an emf. Maybe he confused between magnetic field and electric field?

Comment: It could be that he meant a pair of Helmholtz coils: they generate a nearly uniform magnetic field, but in the cross section look like parallel plates - maybe that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am with @andynitrox on this one - definitely confusing.

In the case of parallel plates and uniform electric field a particle will experience uniform acceleration along the electric field. If you are initially moving perpendicular to the field the trajectory will be a parabola; for a very short time this looks a lot like a segment of a circle and I fact the curvature of the parabola will be the value derived; but as the particle's velocity increases the curvature will be smaller, and the force will no longer be perpendicular to the trajectory of the particle so the equation is no longer valid.

I think you should have a chat with your teacher - somewhere in the chain of knowledge there is a piece missing. I don't know whether it is with me, with you, with the teacher... The only way to find out is to have a conversation. But please don't start it with "the Internet says you are wrong"!

Comment: Yea, I believe it could be a confusion between magnetic field and electric field. And thanks for the tip about the internet :). Thanks for the details.